# -bash: test.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ssh

I have two machines, A and B. In machine B, I have the script file `test.sh`.

I am trying to run that script file from machine A by using the command:

```
ssh -i /home/ec2-user/KEASER_UT_KP.pem ec2-user@10.0.1.67 'bash -s' < /tmp/test.sh
```

It is throwing an error:

> -bash: /tmp/test.sh: No such file or directory

That file is available in the same location, `/tmp`.

Please let us know how to fix this error.

Comment: The pipe is evaluated on machine A.

Comment: 10.0.1.67 is A or B?

Comment: Just use `bash /tmp/test.sh`. `bash -s a b c` lets you start an interactive shell with `a`, `b`, and `c` as positional arguments, where `bash a b c` would attempt to run a script named `a` with arguments `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the quotes:

```
before: ssh [..snip..] 'bash -s' < /tmp/test.sh
after:  ssh [..snip..] 'bash -s < /tmp/test.sh'
```

Since `</tmp/test.sh` is outside of those quotes, it's executed on machine A, not the remote one.